# "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory."

Tags: php, html, iis, localhost

I am new to IIS. So i was unable to predict the error message in localhost. I am struggling with this error, please help me to avoid this error message.

[Error message while run my php page using IIS][[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWMoL.png

Comment: In IIS the first file to be executed in the directory should be either `index.*` or `default.*` (index.php, index.htm, default.php, default.htm etc)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set different start page (not index.* or default.*) than you must create or edit web.config file in project folder like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument enabled="true">
            <files>
                <add value="name_of_start_page.*" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```